# How to Make Masonry Layout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-listview

I am Currently working on a kind of Notes app,
Here I want to stack My Notes in this kind of Position.

[[image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFlUz.jpg)
[image]

I am Trying to achieve Masonry Stacking of these Widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_staggerd_gridview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Flutter Layout Grid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_layout_grid)

[image]

run  `$ flutter pub add flutter_layout_grid` to install

Made with [this](https://github.com/madewithfelt/flutter_layout_grid/blob/main/example/lib/flutter_layout_grid_example.dart) code

```
class PietPainting extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: background,
      child: LayoutGrid(
        columnGap: 12,
        rowGap: 12,
        areas: '''
          r R B B  B
          r R Y Y  Y
          y R Y Y  Y
          y R g b yy
        ''',
        // A number of extension methods are provided for concise track sizing
        columnSizes: [1.0.fr, 3.5.fr, 1.3.fr, 1.3.fr, 1.3.fr],
        rowSizes: [
          1.0.fr,
          0.3.fr,
          1.5.fr,
          1.2.fr,
        ],
        children: [
          // Column 1
          gridArea('r').containing(Container(color: cellRed)),
          gridArea('y').containing(Container(color: cellMustard)),
          // Column 2
          gridArea('R').containing(Container(color: cellRed)),
          // Column 3
          gridArea('B').containing(Container(color: cellBlue)),
          gridArea('Y').containing(Container(color: cellMustard)),
          gridArea('g').containing(Container(color: cellGrey)),
          // Column 4
          gridArea('b').containing(Container(color: cellBlue)),
          // Column 5
          gridArea('yy').containing(Container(color: cellMustard)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PietNamedAreasApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetsApp(
      title: 'Layout Grid Desktop Example',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.white,
      builder: (context, child) => PietPainting(),
    );
  }
}
```